# Geometry problem regarding an isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

Consider the following isosceles triangle (not drawn to scale)

where $\alpha=70^\circ$, $\beta=10^\circ$, $\gamma=20^\circ$ and $\delta=60^\circ$. Find $x$.

A friend gave me this problem a few weeks ago and the only hint I was given was to use elementary geometry, such as *the sum of the interior angles of a triangle equals $180^\circ$*. I concluded that I eventually need to draw extra lines and possibly deduce something from similar triangles, but so far I haven't figured out much. Any ideas? Am I missing some result that is crucial to the proof?

Comment: Similar to [Finding an angle within an 80-80-20 isosceles triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6942/finding-an-angle-within-an-80-80-20-isosceles-triangle)

Comment: duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2319547