# Finding an angle in a $80^\circ$-$80^\circ$-$20^\circ$ triangle (variant involving $70^\circ$ and $60^\circ$)

Tags: geometry

Let CAB be a 20-80-80 triangle, what is the value of DEA? (EAB = 70, DBA = 60)

[image]

I tried creating a parallel of BC passing through D but I didn't get anything. I also tried creating an equilateral triangle with AD as its side but it also did not work.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2319547/409) and/or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1738400/409), but since those don't have accepted answers, closing as duplicate isn't allowed. There are likely other copies of this question floating around on MSE. (Note that there's also a version with a $50^\circ$ angle.) This is a variants of [Langley's Adventitious Angles problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langley%27s_Adventitious_Angles#The_problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

- Calculate some known angles:

$$ACB = 180-(10+70)-(60+20) = 20°$$

$$AEB = 180-70-(60+20) = 30°$$

- Draw a line from point D parallel to AB, labeling the intersection with BC as a new point F and conclude:

$$\triangle DCF \cong \triangle ACB$$

$$CFD = CBA = 60+20 = 80°$$

$$DFB = 180-80 = 100°$$

$$CDF = CAB = 70+10 = 80°$$

$$ADF = 180-80 = 100°$$

$$BDF = 180-100-20 = 60°$$

- Draw a line FA labeling the intersection with DB as a new point G and conclude:

$$\triangle ADF \cong \triangle BFD$$

$$AFD = BDF = 60°$$

$$DGF = 180-60-60 = 60° = AGB$$

$$GAB = 180-60-60 = 60°$$

$\triangle DFG$ (with all angles 60°) is equilateral

$\triangle AGB$ (with all angles 60°) is equilateral

- $\triangle CFA$ with two 20° angles is isosceles, so $FC = FA$
- Draw a line CG, which bisects ACB and conclude:

$$\triangle ACG \cong \triangle CAE$$

$$FC-CE = FA-AG = FE = FG$$

$$FG = FD, so FE = FD$$

- With two equal sides, DFE is isosceles and conclude:

$$DEF = 30+x = (180-80)/2 = 50$$

Comment: ≡ represents "is congruent to"... So wherever you see ≡ , I am talking about triangles and at other places, it is about angles or sides. A MathJax edit would be appreciated :)

Comment: What symbol would you like to use for "is congruent to"? Would you like $\equiv$? You get that by using \equiv.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The one with a ~ above the =

Comment: OK, that's \cong $\cong$

Comment: So, are you going to make the edits, Soumyadwip?